# pg_upgrade unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directory"

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Postgresql from 9.2 to 9.3 in Fedora 18 using this command as the postgres user

```
$ pg_upgrade -b /bin -B /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin -d /var/lib/pgsql/data -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/ -j 2 -u postgres
```

The error in the log

> command: "/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/pgsql/data" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directory='/var/lib/pgsql'" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
>   waiting for server to start....FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directory"
>   .... stopped waiting
>   pg_ctl: could not start server

As pointed by **a_horse** in the comments that parameter was replaced by `unix_socket_directories` (plural) in 9.3. But the server version being started is the old one 9.2:

```
$ /bin/pg_ctl --version
pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That parameter has been renamed to `unix_socket_directories`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-3.html#AEN114343

Comment: @a_horse That command tries to start version 9.2. Check the updated question

Comment: To explicitly see which parameter is being used in your distribution, you can run `postgres --describe-config | grep -o 'unix_socket_director\w*'`

Answer (score 31):

I hacked the problem by running (as root):

```
mv /usr/bin/pg_ctl{,-orig}
echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/bin/pg_ctl
echo '"$0"-orig "${@/unix_socket_directory/unix_socket_directories}"' >> \
     /usr/bin/pg_ctl
chmod +x /usr/bin/pg_ctl
```

Run `pg_upgrade` as intended, then undo the hack:

```
    mv -f /usr/bin/pg_ctl{-orig,}
```

The problem is that pg_upgrade executes the program pg_ctrl with arguments that specify files in the old "unix_socket_directory" rather than the new "unix_socket_directories" (note the second is plural). This hack renames the original `/usr/bin/pg_ctl` to `/usr/bin/pg_ctl-orig`, and then creates a shell script in its place that simply calls the original pg_ctl program, passing all arguments with any strings "unix_socket_directory" changed to "unix_socket_directories".

In bash, one can change a portion of a string, say from `bar` to `baz` in a variable `$foo`, by using `${foo/bar/baz}` (note this does not change the variable, but rather returns the variable's modified contents). Arrays can also be used with `${x/y/z}` to retrieve an array with all of its contents replaced, all at once. The variable `$@` is an array that contains all arguments passed to the program/script/function, so the new pg_ctl script executes the old one with all arguments changed from the old directory name to the new one.

Comment: this really allowed me to upgrade postgres 9.2 to 9.6 on Centos 7! Thanks!

Comment: Worked great for me going from 9.2 to 9.6. Thanks so much! No idea what I would have done without this answer!

Comment: Worked for me too, going from 9.2 to 9.6 on Centos 7

Comment: Maybe explaining the trickery of the bash hack could help others deal with similar problems in future. This is some serious bash twisting :-)

Comment: Excellent & elegant solution, worked flawlessly for going from PostgreSQL 9.2 to 10.7 on CentOS 7

Comment: A simple, perfectly working solution. Saved me from writing something like that myself in the middle of the night. Very short and elegant bashism with slashes-replace. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same problem. I was upgrading from Fedora Repo's 9.2.4 to PGDG 9.3. The source of the problem is that Fedora backports changes of parameter `unix_socket_directory` to `unix_socket_directories` (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=853353).

My solution is to rebuild the `pg_upgrade` from sources, with update to file `contrib/pg_upgrade/server.c:199` where `pg_upgrade` checks for server version:

```
199:       (GET_MAJOR_VERSION(cluster->major_version) < 903) ?
```

, in my case i change it to:

```
199:       (GET_MAJOR_VERSION(cluster->major_version) < 900) ?
```

(see my [patch file here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B61oA4W7nBzGQTh4OTQ0SFI1UmM/edit?usp=sharing)).

Comment: Could you please explain why does this fix the issue (to the likes of myself, who are not overly familiar with the sources (beware of the understatement!))?

Comment: As per @a_horse comment above, upstream PostgreSQL have  changed the parameter `unix_socket_directory` to `unix_socket_directories` in version 9.3.

But the Fedora maintainer backports it to lower version. So, `pg_upgrade` from PGDG (PostgreSQL Global Development Group) YUM Repository expects that the 9.2.4 version accepts `unix_socket_directory`, but actually the 9.2.4 from Fedora YUM Repository accepts `unix_socket_directories`.

In this case, because Fedora backports it into version 9.0 onwards, i changed it to use `unix_socket_directories` for version >= 9.0.